# Amazon AWS server cache error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

We have launched a few EC2 instance to test our mobile game application server. We have set the server to create a cache file (virtual_kvs.dat) inside EC2 host locally to write and fetch game data which initially comes from a RDS database so that we may get data almost instantly. Because of some reasons we are not going for your ElastiCache service yet. So we wished to cache our game data locally inside EC2.

At first, the caching seems OK, as the server responses to client mobiles normally. But from time to time, it stops fetching data from the cache file. Because of that the server stops responding and the game stops running. And as the relevant data is already been stored/written in the cache file, the server wont go for RDS to fetch data. If we clear/delete the cache file, the server in EC2 begins to send response again. The cache is stored at " /var/www/html/public/api/virtual_kvs.dat ". All the necessary permissions folder permissions are set in the server.

We cant figure out the exact reason why this is happening. As our game server need to be up and running 24/7, this cache problem is a great hinder.

Is this error happening due to cache size has become big, so it become unreadable ? Or there may have improper data write during client server communication ? When we compare each time the problem occurs, the cache size were 4MB - 45MB. So, we cant be sure that this is due to cache size problem.

Is anyone also faced this issue?

Comment: which instance you use for the task done ? i suggest c4.2xlarge for this kind of task , c4.2xlarge = 8 vCPU count, ram 15 GiB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we found the issue. 
some non Unicode character from arabic text was included in kvs file , and after serialization these getting unreadable .
Great help from below link
https://www.jackreichert.com/2014/02/handling-a-php-unserialize-offset-error/